# Disable jsp precompile in tomcat 7

Tags: jsp, tomcat

How can I disable JSP pre-compilation during tomcat startup (tomcat 7). It adds another 2 minutes to tomcat startup and painful in dev environment.

Comment: I'm pretty sure jsp pre-compilation is disabled by default on a vanilla tomcat installation... Tomcat compiles the JSPs when you first visit the web page. Perhaps you're using a 'special' tomcat setup?

Comment: http://progrnotes.blogspot.com/2015/01/disable-jsp-compilation-on-tomcat.html